# Multiple updates simultaneously on same document in solr

Tags: solr, commit, updates

I have a doubt regarding solr document update. For example, when two requests to update a document in solr comes at the same time, How does solr work?

- Does it take one request randomly and locks write before next request comes in?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different Locking mechanisms as mentioned in [Lucene locking factory docs](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/AvailableLockFactories). By default NativeFSLockFactory is used in which file lock is acquired for the document that is being indexed. The settings for using a different locking mechanism can be changed in solrconfig.xml

Here is a snippet from solconfig.xml

```
<!-- LockFactory 

     This option specifies which Lucene LockFactory implementation
     to use.

     single = SingleInstanceLockFactory - suggested for a
              read-only index or when there is no possibility of
              another process trying to modify the index.
     native = NativeFSLockFactory - uses OS native file locking.
              Do not use when multiple solr webapps in the same
              JVM are attempting to share a single index.
     simple = SimpleFSLockFactory  - uses a plain file for locking

     Defaults: 'native' is default for Solr3.6 and later, otherwise
               'simple' is the default

     More details on the nuances of each LockFactory...
     http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/AvailableLockFactories
-->
<lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about physical locks or logical version control? For logical version control, Solr 4+ supports optimistic concurrency using *version* field.

You can read about it:

1. [Official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents)
2. [Detailed writeup](http://heliosearch.org/solr/optimistic-concurrency/)