# Elasticsearch Update Race Condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index with documents following this format:

```
REQUEST: 
GET /users/_doc/1

RESPONSE:
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "num_followers": 123456,
    "num_photos": 123456
}
```

Say I have two processes that update the same document almost simultaneously:

```
REQUEST 1:
POST /users/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.name = 'Bar'"
    }
}


REQUEST 2:
POST /users/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.num_followers = 0"
    }
}
```

One of these requests will hit the cluster first. How does ES handle the request that arrives second? Is there some internal queue/time-stamping logic that ensures all updates modify the document in order and no requests are lost?

Additionally, would I benefit by implementing some sort of batching logic that handles the request ordering on my end and issues one update call to ES or is this not necessary?

Comment: not sure about elasticsearch, for example solr has built-in lock mechanisms, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821568/multiple-updates-simultaneously-on-same-document-in-solr   Assuming that the lock mechanism is a feature of Lucene library (which is common for both solr and elasticsearch) , I suspect that elasticsearch might have lots of common things with solr

Comment: check this answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71078942/10127261