# How to handle race-condition (Synchronisation) in Java project using ElasticSearch as persistence

Tags: java, elasticsearch, data-persistence

**Problem**: We have data stored in DB. For example, take a USER object which is stored. CRUD operations can occur on any of the USER. 
Is there any efficient way in which I can make these cruds as thread-safe if simultaneous operations come for the same USER.

**My Solution**

1. We use a Cache like a concurrent map which will help in holding the lock on **specific** OID if it is being worked upon.

The issue with this approach is we are having an additional cache, which will be handled in various scenarios like system restart and all.

Is there any other way in which I can achieve this which is much efficient. Anything can be done in persistence layer itself ?

**PS: I am not using any Framework.**

Comment: If a user is unique, I don't see any concurrency issues.

Comment: User is just an example. Multiple admins, having CRUD on same USERs

Comment: I think handling it in persistence layer is enough unless you want to add another layer of complexity in your application (Cache,MQ). You can maintain a lockFlag in the table once a user fetch that record in the db. Some database supports this implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `_seq_no` and `_primary_term`.
You should read the document from the elastic search and retrieve sequence number and primary term:

```
request:
GET example-index/_doc/FOjCPXdy5uFjy80o4vxPI4kzlRQo

response:
{
  "_index" : "example-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "FOjCPXdy5uFjy80o4vxPI4kzlRQo",
  "_version" : 2,
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "data": "text"
  }
}
```

then pass them with your update query:

```
request:
POST example-index/_update/FOjCPXdy5uFjy80o4vxPI4kzlRQo?if_seq_no=1&if_primary_term=1
{
  "doc":{
     "data": "updated text"
  }
}
```

so if the other agent updated your document those parameters will change after and you will get error 409:

```
response:
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason" : "[FOjCPXdy5uFjy80o4vxPI4kzlRQo]: version conflict, required seqNo [1], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [2] and primary term [1]",
        "index_uuid" : "GUZKnab3T5aBlzXEuOPI7Q",
        "shard" : "0",
        "index" : "example-index"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason" : "[FOjCPXdy5uFjy80o4vxPI4kzlRQo]: version conflict, required seqNo [1], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [2] and primary term [1]",
    "index_uuid" : "GUZKnab3T5aBlzXEuOPI7Q",
    "shard" : "0",
    "index" : "example-index"
  },
  "status" : 409
}
```

documentation: [elastic.co/optimistic-concurrency-control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/optimistic-concurrency-control.html)